# Scaling a circle with cosine

Tags: trigonometry, circles, transformation

Take a simple circle:

[image: simple circle]

Scale it down (2 methods):

[image: simple circle scaled down 1]

-or-

[image: simple circle scaled down 2]

Now, with that same simple circle, add a cosine variant:

[image: complex circle]

How can the cosine variant be scaled without distorting the original shape?  That is, how can the x-values from the original shape be preserved by scaling/translating them down to overlay on the smaller simple circle?

[image: circles and cosine]

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I don't want to convert it into a circle.  I want to take the blue-horned shape and scale it down to sit on the red circle, just as the blue-horned shape sits on top of the black circle.  Is there a method for doing that?  So far, the methods I've tried always distort the original shape of the blue-horned circle as I scale it down.

Comment: Scale the right-hand side by $1/2^2$ and apply a compensating transformation to the argument to $\cos$ so that it uses the original, unscaled $x$-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general answer.

We need two geometric transformations: [translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)) and [homothecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation).

Given a curve with equation $F(x,y)=0$, you may translate the curve by vector $\vec u$: replace the equation by $F(x-u_x,y-u_y)=0$.

Likewise, given a curve with equation $F(x,y)=0$, you may apply a homothecy of center $O$ (the origin of coordinates) and ratio $\lambda$: replace the equation by $F(x/\lambda,y/\lambda)=0$.

---

Here, we would like a homothecy of ration $1/2$, but with center at $(1,2)$. We will apply a translation to move the center of homothecy to $O$, then apply the homothecy, then translate back.

Step by step:

1. Initial curve: $(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2=4+\cos(\pi x)$.
2. After the first translation: $x^2+y^2=4+\cos(\pi x+\pi)=4-\cos(\pi x)$.
3. After the homothecy: $4x^2+4y^2=4-\cos(2\pi x)$.
4. After the second translation: $4(x-1)^2+4(y-2)^2=4-\cos(2\pi x)$.

The equation of the scaled curve is thus

$$4(x-1)^2+4(y-2)^2=4-\cos(2\pi x)$$

Illustration:

[image]